# Report - Recreate Standard Report Type

Tags: community, reporting, custom-report-type

There is a standard report type Campaign with Contacts that has almost everything I need.  Is it possible to clone this report type?  If not, what objects should I join in my custom report type to get campaign name, campaign member status,  Contact First Name, Contact Phone, Account ID, Account Owner ID?

My current setup is Campaign inner join to Contact outer join to Account.  I'm getting the fields that I needed but Account fields display no information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not Go In to the Report and just Save As? Or create a custom report Type?